# Ordenar documentos anidados por fechas en Mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Estoy trabajando con documentos de mongodb que representan a un usuario similares a estos

```
{
  "avatar":"https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/150/150.jpg",
  "chats":[
    {
        "_id":"5ebf327f58581825842c3e7c",
        "user":{
          "avatar":"https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/150/150.jpg",
          "_id":"5eb62f3b94bca83a60c09b81",
          "username":"qwerty1"
        },
        "room":{
          "messages":[],
          "_id":"5ebf327f58581825842c3e7b",
          "lastModified":"2020-05-16T00:23:27.632Z",
        },
    },
    {
        "_id":"5ebf335bae74a02814c757cb",
        "user":{
          "avatar":"https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/150/150.jpg",
          "_id":"5ebcbea4afca7232c892e548",
          "username":"qwerty2"
        },
        "room":{
          "messages":[],
          "_id":"5ebf335bae74a02814c757ca",
          "lastModified":"2020-05-16T00:27:07.667Z",
        },
    }
  ],
  "_id":"5eb38cade01cba26341d0c51",
  "username":"qwerty",
  "email":"qwerty@qwerty.com"
}
```

Necesito que los chats están ordenados por la fecha que está en ***lastModified*** de ***room***, de más reciente a más antiguo.

He probado con esto

```
User
  .findById(_id)
  .populate({
    path: 'chats',
    populate: {
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username avatar'
    }
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'chats',
    populate: 'room'
  })
  .sort('-chats.room.lastModified');
```

Donde espero que el resultado sea el chat de username ***qwerty2*** primero y ***qwerty1*** después, pero como resultado los obtengo en el orden que mostré al inicio.

Comment: Sabria como hacerlo con javascript puro, pero no he usado mongodb, y asumo que no quieres ordenar informacion en el front, si no que deseas que ya te llegue ordenada por la fecha desde el backend... si depronto tambien estas abierto a hacer esta ordenacion en el frontend en vez del backend entonces puedo ayudarte.

Comment: @Riven Así es, estoy tratando que el frontend no tenga tanta complejidad, aunque es la solución que veo más práctica en este momento, creo que sabría hacerlo, pero acepto cualquier ayuda u opinión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay necesidad de que ordenes con javascript ya con mongoose tienes la posibilidad de que te venga ordenado.

```
User
  .findById(_id)
  .populate({
    path: 'chats',
    populate: {
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username avatar'
    }
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'chats',
    populate: 'room',
    options: { sort: { 'lastModified': -1 } }
  })
```

También recomendarte que mongoose cuenta con un updateAt que puedes ponerlo en la creación del schema.
De este modo no necesitarías crear un campo lastModified, automáticamente te gestiona que cuando haya una actualización en el documento te actualice el campo updateAt para poner la fecha de última modificación.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte de updateAt, respecto al codigo 

`.populate({
    path: 'chats',
    populate: 'room',
    options: { sort: { 'lastModified': -1 } }
  })`

Lo he intentado de esta forma pero tampoco funciona

`.populate({
        path: 'chats',
        populate: {
          path: 'room',
          options: { sort: { 'updatedAt': -1 } }
        }
 })`

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problemas  que tu ya te ha funcionado ? @kristiandrex

Comment: @Janpweb esto fue lo que hice:

``` js
const user = await User.findById(_id);

const chats = await Chat
    .find({ owner: _id })
    .populate({
    path: 'user',
    select: 'username avatar'
    })
    .populate('messages')
    .sort('-updatedAt');

user.chats = chats;
```

Buscar el usuario y los chats por separado, ordenar los chats y asignarlos al usuario.